# Calling a boolean function for Trigger WHEN conditions

Tags: postgresql, trigger

The following,

```
CREATE TRIGGER _trigger_insert_form_metadata
AFTER INSERT
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN _conditions_form_metadata(NEW)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE _trigger_insert_form_metadata_function();
```

It getting the error,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_conditions_form_metadata"
LINE 5: WHEN _conditions_form_metadata(NEW)
```

The function successfully creates,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _conditions_form_metadata(doc jsonb)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN (doc ->> 'type') = 'data_record'
      AND (doc #>> '{contact,_id}') IS NOT NULL
      AND (doc ->> 'form') IS NOT NULL;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to call the function for the WHEN conditions because I need several triggers with identical conditions.

What it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is defined to accept a `jsonb` parameter not a record of type `my_table`. Additionally, the condition after a `when` has to be enclosed in parentheses.

Assuming `my_table` has a `jsonb` column called `doc` you need to change the call to:

```
when (_conditions_form_metadata(new.doc))
```

Alternatively you need to change `_conditions_form_metadata` to accept a record of type `my_table`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _conditions_form_metadata(p_row my_table)
```

Then access the JSONB column using `(p_row.doc ->> 'type')`